# Batch file to open and sort a folder that has an unknown path

Tags: search, batch-file, find, directory

**If you think I don´t deserve any help because I almost got no code myself,
just help me out with the "Find the folder and open it" part.
I´ve got good code for that and just need a stupid environmental variable that acts as the path before my known path. Please.**

---

**I am looking for a batch code that does the following:**

- Open the cmd window and display the following message inside of it in a **big font**:

  *Press Enter to open the Skyrim Data folder.*
- If Enter is pressed,

  search for a folder of which I only know the last bit of the folder path,
  that is *\common\Skyrim\Data*.

The folder that I want it to find is this ***Data*** folder.
The folder path could be on any drive and there could be a random number of folders with different names (and maybe spaces) before *\common\Skyrim\Data*, but there is only one Data folder that is on the end of this exact path.

- If the folder wasn´t found,

  don´t close the the cmd window automatically.

  Display *Folder could not be found. Press a button to exit.*

  Close the cmd window when a button is pressed.
- If the folder was found,

  stop searching any further.

  Open the folder in **detailed view**,

  sort it so it shows the newest files on top of everything else.

  **(Detailed View, Date Modified, Ascending)**

  Close the cmd window automatically.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Here is what I have:

@ECHO OFF

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "\common\Skyrim\Data"

I want the .bat to work regardless of Windows version,
so it should be able to work on x64 and x82 machines, Windows 8,7,Vista,XP.
I want it so EVERYONE (on windows) can use it to find and open their Skyrim Data folder.

Comment: Try googling "How to write a batch file". This site is designed to help those who get stuck or fixing a mistake, but in either case the person tried. This is simply a request for someone to write code for you.

Comment: Yea... I am stuck. I did search google for for a long time and couldn´t even find how to find and open the folder. What I DID find, was this website. I really looked. I even checked the environmental variables, but none worked. ;%PATH% might have worked but it didn´t. Maybe I placed it wrong. If you dont think I tryed, just ignore most of what I wish to have and only help me out with Finding and opening the folder. I´ve got good code for that. I just need the Variable to handle everything before my known path. I´d really appreciate that.

Comment: Did you vote down my Question? :( Can I not edit a comment more than 2x? I can´t edit my other comment, so I created this new one, just to let you know that voting down this Question is not neccessary cause I did put some effort in my research.

Comment: And my Question is useful and clear. It doesn´t SHOW research effort, but it IS useful and clear. so one is bad, the other is good. Which makes it neutral.

Comment: Do you mind if the script needs an administrator permissions (you can create a shortcut that will set them automatically) ?

Comment: By the way it will be nearly impossible to open the explorer in "detailed view" mode in simple batch file...And will take a looonng time for the search..

Comment: Hello npocmaka, do you mean the .bat must be run "as an administrator"? I don´t really want an extra shortcut, only the .batch file, which does all the work. If it´s needed to run the .bat as an administrator, isn´t it enough to right-click the .bat file and select "Run as Administrator"? If an extra shortcut IS required, I´d be fine with that though. I would need the code for that then aswell... EDIT: OK, let´s ignore the detailed view. And can´t we speed up the search by telling the bat to start at the C:/ drive?

Comment: Most of the time the folder will be at either C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data or C:\Program Files (86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\Data. So if the .bat starts searching there, and then stops the search after it finds it, it won´t take long, will it? EDIT: Hey, thanks for counter-voting my Question! :)

Comment: I got a better way- it's written in the registry and will take much less time if take it from there.Still requires admin permissions.And yes it will be enough to run it as administrator.

Comment: By the way, this is the kind of thing that a batch file is really not cut out for. I'd recommend a simple Winform (they're really easy to make) and you get your choice of several full programming languages, all of which probably have libraries to handle the search.

Comment: check my answer..It should be faster than searching directories.Still I don't know how to open detailed view in batch.

Comment: @npocmaka: Thing is, I want other people to use that .bat file without much hassle. I am working on a tutorial which teaches how to install a Skyrim mod, and I want to include a .batch file which does what I want it to do, to help out unexperienced modders. I don´t want them to struggle with their folder labyrinth, sorting options and other stuff, when they just can run a .batch that does it for them instead.

Comment: @Endoro: Does your code search my folder? Because the cmd window was there for some time and then disappeared. I added "pause" to make it stay open but it doesn´t show my folder path.

Comment: @Garan: I... don´t even know what you´re talking about. My only programming knowledge comes from google research results with nice explanations and from modding some game .ini files. I can´t even open a folder lol. How would I manage to create a Winform.

Comment: @Dani Please don't edit code in answers and use comments like `Would you maybe not reject changes to my own code this time? I did not create it, but it was created for me!` as the reason. This is not your code. Best thing to do would be notify the user of how to improve it.

Comment: @Popeye: Why is the "edit" button there then? When I first did edits, I had a reasonable comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2905349) but it got rejected. I don´t understand why I am not allowed to change code, that was written for me, to better match my conditions. It´s not even code changes, it´s just words.

Comment: @Dani reasons for edits : 
    `to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes`, 
    `to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it`,
    `to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages`
    `to add related resources or hyperlinks`                         Whilst your edit has good intentions, this edit could lead to errors in the code which may end up getting the original poster downvotes. Recommended why is to tell the user where to improve and let them do it themselves. Luckily for you your edit was approved by the poster.

Comment: @Popeye: I was wondering why that didn´t happen the first time. When it said "your edits will get reviewed" I thought the author would be the one doing that. I did not expect other people do do that as well. But what you say does make sense, I could get the author some downvotes by ruining their code, that was not the intention. But I honestly thought that only the author would review the changes.

Comment: @Dani no it goes into a review process unless the author gets to it first. I found it in the review process. If you choice to edit someone elses' code you need to be 110% sure it is correct or that theirs is so messed up it wouldn't matter. In all honesty I try to avoid any code edits all together whether it question or answer. If it is question it could affect the out come of the answers or you could fix the issue that they are actually having by editing it so then everything looks fine and like I have said you could do more damage then good with editing code in answers.

Comment: @Popeye: I see. Well I was sure my code changes were correct, for it was just text that I modified. And, by editing it myself, I received +2 Rep., which is good, because I´m actually getting closer to being able to upvote this code. Which would let me show some appreciation to the author. Regardless, I thank you for your heads up and tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::-Open the Skyrim Data folder-
::This will run on 64/32 bit systems
::and on Windows XP/Vista/7/8
::from any directory without knowing drive or path
::And will be faster than brute force search.
::Batch code by npocmaka, tiny edits by Dani.
::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704093/batch-file-to-open-and-sort-a-folder-that-has-an-unknown-path
::No sorting feature yet.
::No automatic file archiving yet.

@echo off
mode con cols=75 lines=50
echo(
echo(
echo(
echo                                 A          j
echo                                #M,         N#
echo                               QM*~         *MM
echo                              pM9            lM^&
echo                             gN#    p         dM&
echo                            jMMV    M^&        l@N^&
echo                           jMM8    yMMMM#-     M#M^&
echo                          _MMMP    MMMMMMm,    )NMMg
echo                         ,MMMM    4M7^   "7&    MMMMg
echo                        _MMMM8    "~      jM    l#MMM,
echo                       _MMMMM^&          _pMF    jMNMMMc
echo                       #MMMMMMMc    _gNM5~'    #MMMMMMM,
echo                      BMMMMM   `   NMMM           MMMMM#
echo                     #MMMMM8       ~QM            ]MMMMM^&
echo                    pMMMMMM    _   , MMg      _    #MB#MM^&
echo                   4MMMMMM#    MNgp#, MMM _ggMF    #MMMMMM^&
echo                   "MMMMMMMMmmgNMMMMM^&MMMMMMMMMggmMMMMNMMMf
echo                    "#MMMMMg2**#ZMMMMMN#MMMMM2@**~QMMMMMMF
echo                     =MMNRMMMMMMMMMMMM@MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMP
echo                      7MM^&B@MBMMMMMMM!^NMNMMMMMMMMMMNMM#
echo                       #MMWMMMM4MN2MMMpJMMMMBM7~MNMNMM@
echo                        QMMMZ"   ~  *MQ7MM' M^  "MMMMN
echo                         PMQf]       ^@~MM      ' #MM'
echo                          #Mp1        ] 4M       gMM'
echo                          `MMMg        , M     _#BM'
echo                           "MMMMp,     [r"   _gMM@(
echo                            +MMMMI    j@    ]#MMM9
echo                             \MMMI   jF,`   ]BMMF
echo                              \#MI  jZv      #M'
echo                               YM^|   #f
echo                                G^|   ,^&
echo                                    _#,
echo                                   yM/
echo                                   M^&
echo                                   `Mg,g*^^
echo                                    ^|QM# !
echo                                     "QT/
echo                                      "7

echo(
echo(
echo(
echo                   Searching for the Skyrim Data folder...
echo(
echo(



color
::for 64bit systems
REGEDIT.EXE  /E "%temp%\skyrim.REG" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bethesda Softworks\Skyrim"
::for 32bit systems
if errorlevel 1 REGEDIT.EXE  /E "%temp%\skyrim.REG" "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Bethesda Softworks\Skyrim"
color
if not exist "%temp%\skyrim.REG" (
    echo  DONE! - Folder not found.
    pause >nul
    exit /b 1
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%S in ('type "%temp%\skyrim.REG" ^|find "Installed Path"') do (
    set "skyrim_folder=%%~S"
)
set "skyrim_folder=%skyrim_folder:\\=\%"
del "%temp%\skyrim.REG" /S /Q >nul 2>&1
echo                                Opening:
echo        ~~ %skyrim_folder%Data ~~
start explorer "%skyrim_folder%Data"
exit /b 0

goto :eof
::Do not use the following - Will take ages.

rem  ::
rem  :: find available disk drives
rem  ::

for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%D in ('fltmc volumes | findstr /C:"NTFS" /C:"FAT"') do (
    set "disk_drives=%%D;"
)
rem  ::
rem  :: search
rem  ::
for %%P (%disk_drives%) do for /f %%S in ('dir /b /s a:d %%P\*data ^|find "\common\Skyrim\Data"') do (
    start explorer "%%S" && exit /b 0
)
echo skyrim not found
pause
```

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome code! You have even added Skyrim logo! It works nicely too! Thank you!! Now,... would it be too much to ask for a sorting feature? We can ignore the "Detailed view" but can we make it so it sorts Date Modified, Ascending? (Newest files on top of everything else) I am also not sure what you mean with "copy mod files there". EDIT: I can´t upvote your code because of missing reputation :(

Comment: /just updated the code and added some improvements/.Unfortunately I have no control over the explorer.exe with batch.I can sort the files with the console and print them , but manipulating the window will require more complex tool (e.g. powershell)

Comment: Probably you want to copy some `esp` and `esm` files there.This could be done with the script.Even unpacking them from a zip

Comment: Awww... still not enough reputation to vote :( About the .esp and .esm: It´s the other way around. I want to take them OUT of the folder. Thing is, by installing a Skyrim Steam Workshop mod, it places the files there automatically, but I don´t want them there (yet). I want to install them with a mod manager. I´ll have to archive them and import them into the mod manager. We do not know which files the Workshop installes. (could be a .bsa + .esp or just an .esp) Because of that, I wanted the folder sorted, so the user can see WHICH files are new and remove them from the folder.

Comment: The user has to: Open their Data folder, sort it so it shows the newest files on top of everything else, fish out the newest files that belong to the mod, place them inside a new folder called Data, pack the new Data folder into an .zip archive, import that archive into their mod manager. I don´t think ALL of this can be done with a simple .bat, can it?

Comment: @Endoro: Yea, it´s great, isn´t it? hehe. btw. do you know why your code isn´t working for me? Maybe I am using it wrong? Is it supposed to show me my complete folder path?

Comment: @Dani as I'm smarter person than I look it just occurred to me to check this directory `%appdata%\..\Local\Skyrim`.Tadaaam .There you have listed in these text files all installed mods.So I can filter them in the folder using the information there :-).Just check them and tell me what you want ...

Comment: OK people. I´m off for today. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: `type "%appdata%\..\Local\Skyrim\SteamModList.txt" | find ".esp"`  This will list all mod installed with steam workshop.And yes I can copy them and pack them in a zip

Comment: I´m afraid I can´t test this for now. I had to move and now I don´t have any access to the pc where Skyrim is installed. I´ve only got my little laptop here. I can´t even download Skyrim here because my only internet is a shitty mobile internet stick... I won´t be coming back until Friday as well. Would you like to see the tutorial I created? Maybe it will show you exectly what I want to accomplish. I take it you play Skyrim aswell? :) So maybe my tutorial will help you a bit with modding. Or maybe it wont... I guess I can´t teach such a skilled coder anything new hehe.

Comment: Nevер dealt with Skyrim modding  :-) so yes.You can write to me on `npocmaka@gmail.com` to avoid discussions here .

Answer (score 1):

try to find your path:

```
set "skypath="
for /f %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s \data ^| findstr /i "\\common\\Skyrim\\Data$"') do set "skypath=%%~fa"
if defined skypath (echo %skypath%) else echo not found!
```

Comment: Does your code search my folder? Because the cmd window was there for some time and then disappeared. I added "pause" to make it stay open but it doesn´t show my folder path.

Comment: @npocmaka it searches from root directory. Please do not spread hoaxes.

Comment: My mistake 0_o .BUT ,it does not search in all drives. To find all hard disk drives and filter out flash cards and cd-roms requires few more lines code.

Comment: @npocmaka if I try `fltmc volumes` I get `Volume listing failed with error: 0x80070005` in Win8.

Comment: It requires admin permissions.But my check is incomplete.I'll need also to find which devices support `Disk Quotas` with `>fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo z:` to filter out flash cards.